# Conjugate momenta in field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, classical-field-theory

In classical mechanics for particles, the Euler-Lagrange equations are given by:

$\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial q}$

and the momentum conjugate to q is defined as:

$p = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q}$.

In particular, the conjugate momentum shows up on the L.H.S. of the Euler-Lagrange equations. However, in field theory, the Euler-Lagrange equations are given by:

$\partial_\mu \frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial_\mu \phi)} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \phi}$

and the conjugate momenta are defined as:

$\pi = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot \phi}$.

In this case, the conjugate momentum is different from the term that appears in the derivative on the L.H.S. of the Euler-Lagrange equation.

What causes this difference between particle theory and field theory?

Comment: Fields are functions of spacetime, while the $q$'s are a function of time alone.

Comment: I understand that aspect, but I'm mainly curious why the useful definition is

$\pi = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot \phi}$

rather than 

$\pi^\mu = \frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial_\mu \phi)}$. The later definition seems to be a closer in analogy.

Comment: You can define $\pi^\mu$ if you want. However, $\pi$ is also used as the canonical momentum in the Hamiltonian formulation. Hamiltonians generate evolution in _time_, regardless of how many spatial dimensions there are. Since the formulation singles out time, it turns out you only want $\pi$ and not the full $\pi^\mu$.